# Geofencing didEnterRegion,didExitRegion function not Calling in iphone 5S 7.1

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone

i have tried this code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region12222 - %@", region.identifier);
    [self showRegionAlert:@"Entering Region" forRegion:region.identifier];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Exited Region - %@", region.identifier);
    [self showRegionAlert:@"Exiting Region" forRegion:region.identifier];
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question so that others can help you (read more about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Specifically, show how you monitor a region and initialise the location manager.

Comment: is this happened only for 5s???.check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152361/startmonitoringforregion-never-calls-didenterregion-didexitregion

Comment: Geofencing didEnterRegion,didExitRegion function not Calling location purpose in iphone 5S 7.1

Comment: didenter region exitregion not fire in ios 7.1 in device iphone 5s location based